# Нужно ли оптимизировать работу fedora 26 на ssd?

Tags: linux, fedora

Нужно ли оптимизировать работу fedora 26 на ssd накопители, выставлять флаги в fstab, или вручную включать trim?

Comment: да, нужно оптимизировать

Comment: Можно подробнее что имено нужно делать?